# Event log data for Process Mining

Tags: data-request

Process mining assumes the existence of an event log where each event refers to a case, an activity, and a point in time. An event log can be seen as a collection of cases and a case as a trace/sequence of events.

Event data may come from a wide variety of sources:

- a database system (e.g., patient data in a hospital),
- a transaction log (e.g., a trading system),
- a business suite/ERP system (SAP, Oracle, etc.),
- a message log (e.g., from IBM middleware),
- an open API providing data from websites or social media,

I am looking for publicly available event logs with csv or xes or any other available formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Process and Data Science Group - RWTH Aachen University

[processmining.org](http://www.processmining.org/event-data.html)

**Available data sets in XES:**

- [Purchase order handling process (BPI Challenge 2019)](https://doi.org/10.4121/uuid:d06aff4b-79f0-45e6-8ec8-e19730c248f1)
- [Payment process of Common Agricultural Policy (BPI Challenge 2018)](https://doi.org/10.4121/uuid:3301445f-95e8-4ff0-98a4-901f1f204972)
- [Loan application process of a Dutch financial institute (BPI Challenge 2017)](https://doi.org/10.4121/uuid:5f3067df-f10b-45da-b98b-86ae4c7a310b)
- [Municipality log 1 (BPI Challenge 2015)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:a0addfda-2044-4541-a450-fdcc9fe16d17)
- [Municipality log 2 (BPI Challenge 2015)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:63a8435a-077d-4ece-97cd-2c76d394d99c)
- [Municipality log 3 (BPI Challenge 2015)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:ed445cdd-27d5-4d77-a1f7-59fe7360cfbe)
- [Municipality log 4 (BPI Challenge 2015)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:679b11cf-47cd-459e-a6de-9ca614e25985)
- [Municipality log 5 (BPI Challenge 2015)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:b32c6fe5-f212-4286-9774-58dd53511cf8)
- [Incident management log (BPI Challenge 2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:500573e6-accc-4b0c-9576-aa5468b10cee)
- [Problem management log, open problems (BPI Challenge 2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:3537c19d-6c64-4b1d-815d-915ab0e479da)
- [Problem management log, closed problems (BPI Challenge 2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:c2c3b154-ab26-4b31-a0e8-8f2350ddac11)
- [Event log of a loan application process (BPI Challenge 2012)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:3926db30-f712-4394-aebc-75976070e91f)
- [Anonymized event log of a Dutch Academic Hospital (BPI Challenge 2011)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:d9769f3d-0ab0-4fb8-803b-0d1120ffcf54)

**Available data sets in CSV:**

- [Purchase order handling process (BPI Challenge 2019)](https://doi.org/10.4121/uuid:d06aff4b-79f0-45e6-8ec8-e19730c248f1)
- [Click-data for the customers that are not logged in to the website (BPI Challenge 2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:9b99a146-51b5-48df-aa70-288a76c82ec4)
- [Click-data for the customers that are logged in to the website (BPI Challenge 2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:01345ac4-7d1d-426e-92b8-24933a079412)
- [Questions asked by customers (BPI Challenge 2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:2b02709f-9a84-4538-a76a-eb002eacf8d1)
- [Messages sent by customers (BPI Challenge 2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:c3f3ba2d-e81e-4274-87c7-882fa1dbab0d)
- [Complaints filed by customers (BPI Challenge 2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:e30ba0c8-0039-4835-a493-6e3aa2301d3f)
- [Change log (BPI Challenge 2014)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:679b11cf-47cd-459e-a6de-9ca614e25985)
- [Incident log (BPI Challenge 2014)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:3cfa2260-f5c5-44be-afe1-b70d35288d6d)
- [Interaction log (BPI Challenge 2014)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:3d5ae0ce-198c-4b5c-b0f9-60d3035d07bf)
- [Incident activity log (BPI Challenge 2014)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:86977bac-f874-49cf-8337-80f26bf5d2ef)
- [Incident management log (BPI Challenge 2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:500573e6-accc-4b0c-9576-aa5468b10cee)
- [Problem management log, open problems (BPI Challenge 2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:3537c19d-6c64-4b1d-815d-915ab0e479da)
- [Problem management log, closed problems (BPI Challenge 2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:c2c3b154-ab26-4b31-a0e8-8f2350ddac11)
- [Anonymized event log of a Dutch Academic Hospital (BPI Challenge 2011)](http://dx.doi.org/10.4121/uuid:d9769f3d-0ab0-4fb8-803b-0d1120ffcf54)

Answer (score 1):

[Road Traffic Fines dataset](https://data.4tu.nl/articles/dataset/Road_Traffic_Fine_Management_Process/12683249) from an Italian policing context.